# Class overloading?

Tags: c++, class

Can I have a class in C++, in different .hpp files?

Because I have a class called Map which is about 5000 lines and I wonder know if I can split it in two or three files with the same class name, and if other headers will see this class like if it wasn't split.

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with overloading.

Comment: Welcome to the party! Please [take the tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour), which will help you to understand what this site is (and what it isn't). You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, you can't do that.**

Besides, your class is *way* too big. Instead of trying to split it up lexically, consider splitting it up *semantically*, into multiple classes. Read about the *single responsibility principle*.

In short, there is a moderately serious design problem at the core of this question.

Comment: Thank you @Lightning Racis in Obrit!

Comment: You can pull method definitions out of the header though, even if its a template. You can just put the methods externally, in another header. `class Test { void f(); }; /*Other header*/ inline void Test::f() {}`

Comment: @VoidStar: I _knew_ someone was going to bring that up. We're not talking about member function definitions; we're talking about the class definition.

Comment: Yeah it just seems like to reach 5000 lines, they very likely have code in methods inside the class definition, and it's just a different way to split up the header file. I'm not sure the asker realized this was even an option.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not an option. You need the entire class header in a single place to be included for. 5000 lines make me think you have code in there. You can certainly put the code from a single class in several .cpp files, just distributing your members around.

Comment: The problem is this, I have a 5000 lines header, and several .cpp files attached to it, in order to avoid work I wonder know if that could be done